# Calculate distance raster avoiding land

Tags: r, gis, distance, r-raster

I'm looking for a way to calculate a raster of distances from a point, similar to what `raster::distance` does, but avoiding land. So, in the same way that I can make a raster of distances to a point (without any constraints) like so:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)


# create cooridnates sp points
col_coord <- data.frame(x      = c(-13.8309),
                        y      = c(28.9942))
coordinates(col_coord) <- ~x+y
col_coord@proj4string <- CRS(projections$WGS84)

#create base raster
baseRaster <- raster(xmn = -80, xmx =55, ymn = -70, ymx = 70, crs = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"), resolution = 1)

#rasterize spatial point
colraster <- rasterize(col_coord, baseRaster)

#calculate distance
coldist <- raster::distance(colraster, doEdge = T)

#plot
plot(coldist)
```

And obtain this image: 
[image]

I would like to make the same raster but of "shortest distance avoiding an area" (in this case land). I'm aware of the package `gdistance` and I've tried to follow the advice on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28595414/calculate-distance-between-2-lon-lats-but-avoid-going-through-a-coastline-in-r) post but this is as far as I've got: (Trans is a transition layer, because it takes a long time to calculate is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/793asokn1l1hv4r/Transition_layer.RData?dl=1).

```
library(gdistance)
# load transition layer (change directory if needed). This is in another CRS so we transform everything
load("data/Transition_layer.RData")

col_coord <- spTransform(col_coord, Trans@crs)
A <- accCost(Trans, col_coord)
plot(A) #this shows high cost in contintents which is good
```

[image]

```
# create a raster for water
mapWGS <- rgeos::gBuffer(rworldmap::getMap(resolution = "high"), width = 0)
water <- rasterize(mapWGS, baseRaster, mask = F, field = 1)
table(is.na(water[]))

water[water == 1] <- 0
water[is.na(water)] <- 1
water[water == 0] <- NA
plot(water)
```

[image]

```
water <- projectRaster(water, crs = Trans@crs)

# change resolution of A to match that of water
A <- resample(A, water)
A2 <- mask(A, water, inverse = F)

plot(A2) # this doesn't make that much sense.
```

[image]

So, any ideas of how to get from this to a raster similar to the first one but containing distances avoiding land would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `raster::gridDistance` with an `omit` argument

```
library(raster)
xy <- data.frame(x=-13.8309, y=28.9942)
r <- raster(xmn=-120, xmx=55, ymn=-70, ymx=70, res=.25)

library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

r <- rasterize(wrld_simpl, r, field= -1)
rr <- rasterize(xy, r, update=TRUE)

x <- gridDistance(rr, 1, omit=-1)
plot(x / 1000000)
points(xy)
```

[image: distance through water]

The maps shows that it works for the Pacific, and also for the Red Sea (because wrld_simpl does not have the Panama and Suez Canals).

But because with gridDistance the path has to go through the centers of raster cells, the estimated distance is a bit longer than the actual distance.

Comment: How would you create a land bridge in R code for one to cross the Panama canal from North America into South America or to cross from Anadyr, Russia, into North America?